# Why is it Artinian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

The following is a part of the section entitled *Samuel functions* in the book *Commutative Ring Theory* by Hideyuki Matsumura:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian semilocal ring, 
>   and $\mathfrak{m}$ the Jacobson radical of $A$.
>   If $I$ is an ideal of $A$ such that for some $\nu >0$,
>   we have $\mathfrak{m}^\nu \subset I \subset \mathfrak{m}$,
>   then the ring $A/I$ is Artinian.

I can't understand why $A/I$ is Artinian. 
If $A$ is a local ring, which is the case in 
*Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and MacDonald, 
$\mathfrak{m}$ becomes the maximal ideal, 
and so $I$ becomes $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal.
In this case I can understand why it is Artinian, 
since the dimension of $A/I$ is $0$.
But, when $A$ is just a semilocal ring, ...

Help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime ideal containing $I$. Since $m^{\nu}\subseteq p$ it follows that $m\subseteq p$. But $m=\cap_{i=1}^n m_i\supseteq \prod_{i=1}^n m_i$, so there is an $i$ such that $p\supseteq m_i$, hence equality. This shows that all primes in $A/I$ are maximal, so $\dim A/I=0$. (In fact, we have proved that $m_i/I$ are the only prime ideals of $A/I$.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that for each product $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n$ where $x_i \in m_i$ there exists $i$ such that $x_i \in p$. But how do we know that $p \supset m_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: @Aki If $p\nsupseteq m_i$ for all $i$ there is $x_i\in m_i-p$ for all $i$. Then what about the product $x_1\cdots x_n$? (It seems you are not aware that an ideal $P$ is prime iff $P\ne A$ and if $P\supseteq IJ$ then $P\supseteq I$ or $P\supseteq J$, where $I,J$ are *ideals* of $A$, which is an equivalent [definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Prime_Ideal) for a prime ideal.)

Comment: I didn't know the alternative definition. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the [Hopkins Levitzki theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem), then an alternative way is to note that $R/I$ is also semilocal and Noetherian, and has nilpotent radical $m/I$, and so by H-L it is also Artinian.

It's a wonderful theorem about the equivalence of the ascending and descending chain conditions for modules over semiprimary rings.

(user26857 elementary answer is to be preferred if you don't know H-L or are otherwise unwilling to use it.)